# How to convert a string into array in delphi?

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, character, punctuation

In php and java there are explode and tokenizer function to convert a string into array without punctuations. Are are functions or some way in delphi to do the work. Suppose there is a large file " This is, a large file with punctuations,, and spaces and numbers 123..." How can we get
array "This is a large file with punctuations and spaces and numbers 123"

Thank you very much in advance.

Yes, we want only [0..9],[a..z],[A..Z], like \w in regex. Can we use regex in Tperlregex to extract \w and put them in Tstringlist as if tstringlist is a array, but it may not be so efficient? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to observe the fact that a string, in essence, *is* an array of characters.

Comment: Based on your example, it looks like you just want to remove commas from a string. Can you please edit your question to be more precise?

Comment: Thank you Andreas Rejbrand and Eugene Mayevski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a function that takes a string and returns an array of strings, these strings being the substrings of the original separated by punctuation, as Eugene suggested in my previous answer, then you can do

```
type
  StringArray = array of string;
  IntegerArray = array of integer;
  TCharSet = set of char;

function split(const str: string; const delims: TCharSet): StringArray;
var
  SepPos: IntegerArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(SepPos, 1);
  SepPos[0] := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(str) do
    if str[i] in delims then
    begin
      SetLength(SepPos, length(SepPos) + 1);
      SepPos[high(SepPos)] := i;
    end;
  SetLength(SepPos, length(SepPos) + 1);
  SepPos[high(SepPos)] := length(str) + 1;
  SetLength(result, high(SepPos));
  for i := 0 to high(SepPos) -  1 do
    result[i] := Trim(Copy(str, SepPos[i] + 1, SepPos[i+1] - SepPos[i] - 1));
end;
```

Example:

```
const
  PUNCT = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '-', '!', '?'];

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  str: string;
begin
  for str in split('this, is, a! test!', PUNCT) do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str)
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the definition of "alphanumerical character" and "puncutation character".

If we for instance define the set of punctuation characters

```
const
  PUNCT = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '-', '!', '?'];
```

and consider all other characters alphanumeric, then you could do

```
function RemovePunctuation(const Str: string): string;
var
  ActualLength: integer;
  i: Integer;
const
  PUNCT = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '-', '!', '?'];
begin
  SetLength(result, length(Str));
  ActualLength := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(Str) do
    if not (Str[i] in PUNCT) then
    begin
      inc(ActualLength);
      result[ActualLength] := Str[i];
    end;
  SetLength(result, ActualLength);
end;
```

This function turns a string into a string. If you want to turn a string into an array of characters instead, just do

```
type
  CharArray = array of char;

function RemovePunctuation(const Str: string): CharArray;
var
  ActualLength: integer;
  i: Integer;
const
  PUNCT = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '-', '!', '?'];
begin
  SetLength(result, length(Str));
  ActualLength := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(Str) do
    if not (Str[i] in PUNCT) then
    begin
      result[ActualLength] := Str[i];
      inc(ActualLength);
    end;
  SetLength(result, ActualLength);
end;
```

(Yes, in Delphi, strings use 1-based indexing, whereas arrays use 0-based indexing. This is for historical reasons.)

Comment: I believe the OP needs a parser function which will take a string and create an array of substrings, extracted by splitting on punctuation marks.

Comment: Ah, I see. (But why didn't he/she say so?)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no built-in functionality like in Java tokenizer. Long time ago we wrote a tokenizer class similar to Java one which became part of ElPack component suite (now LMD ElPack). Here's some [implementation of string tokenizer](http://www.anyang-window.com.cn/stringtokenizer-in-delphi-achieve-functional-modules/) similar to Java one (just found this link in Google, so I can't comment on code quality).